# d3.js with a datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, datepicker

I want d3.js graph is selected by a date range chosen with my datepicker.
The d3.js code is as follows:

```
 </script>

<script id="ejemplo">



function myFunction(){



var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom:30, left: 40},
width = 1300 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.linear()
.range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
.range([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.category10();

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(x)
.orient("bottom");

 var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(y)
.orient("left");

var svg = (d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
 .append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")"));

 d3.json("/projects/chart/data", function(error, data) {
 if (error) throw error;

   data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.sepalLength = +d.sepalLength;
  d.sepalWidth = +d.sepalWidth;
  });

 x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.sepalWidth; })).nice();
 y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.sepalLength; })).nice();


 svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis)
  .append("text")
  .attr("class", "label")
  .attr("x", width)
  .attr("y", -6)
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text("Sepal Width (cm)");

 svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis)
  .append("text")
  .attr("class", "label")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 6)
  .attr("dy", ".71em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text("Sepal Length (cm)")

  svg.selectAll(".dot")
   .data(data)
   .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("class", "dot")
  .attr("r", 3.5)
  .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.sepalWidth); })
  .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.sepalLength); })
  .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.species); });

  var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
  .data(color.domain())
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "legend")
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")";                   });

   legend.append("rect")
     .attr("x", width - 18)
     .attr("width", 18)
     .attr("height", 18)
     .style("fill", color);

   legend.append("text")
    .attr("x", width - 24)
    .attr("y", 9)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .text(function(d) { return d; });

 });
}
 </script>
```

The code views is the next:

```
  @extends('layouts.app')
  @section('title', 'Historical')
  @section('content')

  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<li><a href="/process">   @lang('processdefinition.definition')</a></li>
<li class="active "><a href="/process/executions">   @lang('processdefinition.executions')</a></li>
 </ul>
 <br>
 <ul class="nav nav-pills">
<li class="active "><a href="/process/executions">     @lang('executions.processexecutions')</a></li>
<li ><a href="/process/executions/errors"> @lang('executions.errors')</a>   </li>
<li ><a href="/process/executions/logvolume"> @lang('executions.logvolume')     </a></li>
 <li ><a href="/process/executions/executiontime">       @lang('executions.executiontime')</a></li>
  </ul>
  <br>
  <br>

 <div>
 @include('recursos.datepicker')
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
  <div id="graph"class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-4">
   <button id="demo" type="hidden" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"              role="button"onclick="myFunction()">@lang('executions.search')</button>

 </div>
</div>

 <style type="text/css">   
 #wrapper
  {
    min-width:960px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
  }
   #top
   {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;

}


  #graph{
    width:1100px;
    float:left;  
    margin:0 650px;

  }


  </style>


  @extends('recursos.scatterplot')


 @endsection
```

I want to take the dates from the datepicker and uses this dates in d3.js to show only a range date in my graph.